# Calculate sum of computed observables as total

Tags: knockout.js

My view has 3 properties A,B,C and D is the computed value of A - (B- C). This is represented in grid rows. I would need to sum up the computed columns as a summary total, since I do not have a model property for holding the computed, how or what would be a proper way to calculate the summary.
eg:

```
A     | B      | C    |D   
10      3        2     5 
20      2        1     17
```

For the above, D is the computed column, 10 - (3+2)=5

My model has a single row model, it does not hold all the columns, this model was created by a third party, I cant change it now. Any ideas or heads up would be much appreciated.

View Model:

```
   var selectedRowModel = function(data){
           var A = data.val1;
           var B = data.val2;
           var C = data.val3;
           // D is present per row but once the grid is displayed,I need to evaluate sum of D
           var D = ko.computed(function(){    
               return A -(B+C);
           });
    });
```

Comment: What does you view model look like?

Comment: var selectedRow =  { A :10, B:3, C:2 }

Comment: That's not a view model. Nobody can help you if you don't give them enough information about the problem.

Comment: var selectedRow = self.selected();     <br>  if(selected) { return {A: value, B: value, C: value}; else return "";

Comment: Do you actually have any knockout in place yet - ie is it all working apart from column D?

Comment: Yes.. The column D was data bound using ko.computed over each row. while the totals were being sent by a rest call on the server. But presently due to some calculation errors, need to russle up the totals on the UI. The 3 view model bound columns have been taken care of, but the computed values as they persist only per row call, I am facing issues..

Comment: Can you post the relevant knockout model / current observables etc then - it would help to understand the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mvrh1bn8/) with something like what I think you're trying to do.  I made a view model that holds an observableArray collection of the row data, and includes a function that sums them.  For convenience, it could also be a computed (preferred), or it could be triggered by an event and updated.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>D</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: collection">
        <tr>
            <td><span data-bind="text:A"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text:B"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text:C"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text:D"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
Sum of the D column is: <span data-bind="text: sumD()"></span>
```

Javascript:

```
var Model = function(a,b,c) {
    var self = this;
    self.A = ko.observable(a);
    self.B = ko.observable(b);
    self.C = ko.observable(c);
    self.D = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.A() - (this.B() + this.C());
    }, self);
}

var ModelCollection = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.collection = ko.observableArray([
        new Model(10,3,2),
        new Model(20,2,1)
    ]);
    self.sumD = function() {
        var sum = 0;
        self.collection().forEach(function(item) {
            sum += item.D();
        });
        return sum;
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ModelCollection())
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, but the issue is the model is persistent row wise, I dont have the model (as the entire grid). I only have a row of the grid as a view model..

Comment: Why not create a new view model that wraps the collection as I did, and add functions to it to manipulate it?  You obviously have the data, if it's being displayed at all.  Can you provide more of your source code so we can see the difficulty you're having?

Comment: I understand, but the collection is not as straightforward, as I have posted.. Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
//A | B | C |D
//10 3 2 5 
//20 2 1 17

//For the above, D is the computed column, 10 - (3+2)=5

var model = function(){
  var A = ko.observable(10);
  var B = ko.observable(10);
  var C = ko.observable(10);
  var D = ko.computed(function(){
      return parseInt(A()) - (parseInt(B()) + parseInt(C()));
  });
  
  return {
    A:A,
    B:B,
    C:C,
    D:D
  };
  
}

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: A" /> -
(<input type="text" data-bind="value: B" /> +
<input type="text" data-bind="value: C" />)

<H2 data-bind="text: D"></H2>
```

Comment: [It's recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix) to always use the `radix` parameter with `parseInt`

Comment: Yes pretty close, but the var D is present only per row... :(

Comment: @JamesThorpe True though I will always forget. Btw, if the answer is as simple as this, OP either has no knowledge of KnockoutJS or is really bad at math. @RRR, why is it a problem that "D is only present on row"? Not in the same viewmodel? Simply make `model` in this example a child VM of the row VM to access its properties??

Comment: I think the OP wants to total the columns.